# Can QGIS plot coordinates in Degrees-Minutes format?

Tags: qgis, coordinates, csv

I have a `.csv` file of coordinates that looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way for QGIS to plot coordinates formatted like this?  I've tried *Adding a Delimited Text Layer...* in QGIS, but do not see any options appropriate for this format:

`Nxx.xx.xxx Wxxx.xx.xxx`

I am able to use a [GPS Coordinate Converter](http://boulter.com/gps/) website to convert that data to *Decimal Degrees*, *Degrees, Minutes & Seconds*, and *UTM*.  For example, inputting `N39.56.854 W074.28.013` outputs a latitude of `39.947567`, and longitude of `-74.466883`.  However, I would like to stay in QGIS and make the same conversion.

Things I've tried:

- Created a new `.csv` that has formatting that matches the output of coordinate conversion site mentioned above, and with separated lat-long columns:

  [image]

  However, using the QGIS *Add Delimited Text Layer...* option yields no visualization of the points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 'Add Delimited Text Layer' dialog can add DMS coordinates (DegreeMinutesSeconds). Tick the checkbox DMS coordinates.

[image]

I don't know the QGIS version this was implemented, but it is in QGIS 2.10.1. Remember the x field runs west and y field north.

You need a minor manipulation of your cvs format changing:

```
north west
N39.56.854 W074.28.013
```

to

```
north west
N39'56.854 W074'28.013
```

This can be done in setting an advanced text editor like Notepad++ in column mode, selecting the dot to replace and the replace within in the selection with '.

The QGIS documentation (help button on dialog) says:

> DMS angles: if selected coordinates are represented as
>   degrees/minutes/seconds or degrees/minutes. QGIS is quite permissive
>   in its interpretation of degrees/minutes/seconds. A valid DMS
>   coordinate will contain three numeric fields with an optional
>   hemisphere prefix or suffix (N, E, or + are positive, S, W, or - are
>   negative). Additional non numeric characters are generally discarded.
>   For example N41d54'01.54" is a valid coordinate.

**Update:** 
If you add a separator like comma to you format change, it will also work:

```
latitude, longitude
N39 56.854, W074 28.013
```